# How to search a column for an exact string in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My goal is to search column A for string B and if it is found, return which row it was found in, and if it wasn't found, I would need to know that as well in order to take a different course of action.

My current PHP code:

```
$string = "teststring";
$searchquery = "SELECT *
                  FROM AllStringsTable 
                 WHERE `Column_A` LIKE '$string'"

$searchresult = mysql_query($searchquery) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($searchresult);
echo "The returned row was: $row";
```

This just breaks and does nothing, so I think I'm way off here. Also, I have read that for exact string searching that doesn't require wildcard substrings, etc, LIKE is not needed. So I'm not sure what I would use instead...

Comment: Using Full Text Search (FTS) is a better (incl. performance) approach to situations like these.  But [MySQL native functionality requires that the table(s) be MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).  However, 3rd party tools like Sphinx provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You need the `%` wildcards:

```
// First, prevent sql injection with mysql_real_escape_string
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);

$searchquery = "SELECT * FROM AllStringsTable WHERE `Column_A` LIKE '%{$string}%'";
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------^^^-------^^^

$searchresult = mysql_query($searchquery) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($searchresult) == 0) {
  echo "no rows found";
}
else {

  // You need to loop over the result resource to get all the rows.
  // Better to use mysql_fetch_array()
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchresult)) {
    $print_r $row;
}
```

Comment: why the `%{$string}%` and not just `%$string%`, what is the diff?

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the instant response, I'll try this now and get back with how it works out. Also, yes, I would like to know what's up with the brackets?

Comment: @afarazit, @Rich Haygren If you're referring to the `{}`, they're used in PHP to enclose a variable if it would be hard to tell where the variable name ends.  Most useful for complex things like `$array[0][3]` or `$obj->property` and not strictly necessary here.  Adds readability though.

Comment: @Rich Haygren Please be sure to add the `mysql_real_escape_string()` bit -- very important for security.  BTW, Stack Overflow is all about instant answers.  Welcome to the community!

Comment: So I'm getting I'm not getting an error but it won't go past the point where I make an SQL query request, is that exactly the right syntax for the $searchquery = ... part ? Also, if you need to access the database from inside a function that is called from a function that already has database access, do you need to also create a connection in the sub-function? Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Rich Haygren You should be able to access the existing connection inside a function. It looks like there's a `;` missing at the end of the `$searchquery = ` line.  Fixed above.  You should do `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` while developing to see all your errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do an *exact* match, use **=** instead of **LIKE**:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Column_A = '$string';
```

If you want to do a substring match (which I suspect is more what you want), use **LIKE** with the % wildcards:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Column_A = '%$string%';
```

The difference is that the first query requires that the entire Column_A matches *exactly*.  The second query requires only that the exact word is found somewhere in the column.